# iOS UITableView Edit Mode Circle Border Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to change the border color of the circles shown in a UITableView in edit mode. Currently it is shown in gray, but the circle can't be easily seen when there is a background behind the table.

I was able to update the Selected state using the tintColor property. But what I need is to change the color when the row is unselected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Create custom uitableviewcell in which you can set desired Image of check mark .